# [[maybe_unused]] in if statement doesn't seem to work in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, gcc-warning

The whole point in `[[maybe_unused]]` is that it tells the compiler to not warn for unused variables, right? So why does GCC warn that `ui` is unused, here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define NDEBUG
#include <cassert>

int main()
{   
  std::vector<int> numbers = {1,2,3};

  if ([[maybe_unused]] auto  ui = static_cast<unsigned int>(numbers.size()))
  {
    assert(ui);
    std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in the compiler?

(As an aside: trying this on Wandbox, Clang doesn't seem to warn that `ui` is unused regardless of whether or not the `[[maybe_unused]]` is present).

(Further aside: MSVC also does not warn that `ui` is unused, even if `[[maybe_unused]]` is not present).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a compiler bug to me. The attribute can be applied to any variable declaration and that's a variable declaration.

Filed [91304](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91304).

Comment: From the ticket: Martin Sebor points out that `if (int i [[maybe_unused]] = f()) { }` *does* work.

Comment: Certainly. It accomplishes what I was originally trying to do, though, and so I thought it was worth noting.

Comment: I note also that Clang and MSVC accept `if (int i [[maybe_unused]] = f()) { }` without complaint, so that trick is cross-platform.